# Cast a Char pointer to UINT32

Tags: c

I need to pass a string to a function and assign to UINT32 .

```
void main ()
{
    do_this ("SELF", 18, 100);
}

void do_this(char* comm , UINT32 num , UINT32 value)
{
    UINT32 inl_values[13] ;

    inl_values[0] = (UINT32)comm ;
}
```

I tried to assign the string to inl_values. But I get an error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.

I need to bundle this value into UINT32 and pass the inl_values complete array to a different function. Can someone please tell me how could I solve this.

Comment: Can we see the definition of this "different function" you want to pass `inl_values` to?  `inl_values` is an array of numbers; assigning a string to it makes no sense.

Comment: There you're trying to convert a pointer (a memory address) to an integer. I suspect that what you want is to get the **content** of that address as an integer.

Comment: `inl_values[0] = *((UINT32*)(&comm));` should work. But don't do this unless you have a really good reason. (I'm inclined to think that you don't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your code is calling an API that has a 32-bit opcode as the first parameter, and the author of the API has chosen an opcode such that if he did a combined hex/ASCII dump of your array he would see the ASCII letters "SELF".  For an example of this approach see the nginx configuration code: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/core/ngx_conf_file.h

```
#define NGX_CORE_MODULE      0x45524F43  /* "CORE" */
```

The string "CORE" is in a comment for reference, but the code never uses an actual string.  The symbol is an unsigned 32 bit integer and can be used anywhere an int is required. However the 4 bytes of the int (reading backwards - little endian) are 0x43 ('C'), 0x4F ('O'), 0x52 ('R') and 0x45 ('E)

I recommend you follow the same approach - instead of creating an ASCII string "SELF" and doing the math to convert it to an integer, let the compiler do the work.

```
#define SELF_CODE  0x464C4553   /* "SELF" */
```

Using this new constant, rewrite your code to avoid using any strings:

```
void main ()
{
    do_this (SELF_CODE, 18, 100);
}

void do_this(UINT32 comm , UINT32 num , UINT32 value)
{
    UINT32 inl_values[13] ;

    inl_values[0] = comm ;
}
```